# Get textfield value onblur() dynamically for each row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am a beginner here seeking help.

I have a HTML table loaded with data from the database, and an edit but against each row. When the edit button is clicked, a modal is launched pre-loaded with the db data. There a blank field in the modal with I am seeking to populate dynamically once the first text field is onblur(). But this is working on the first row only. Subsequent rows are not working.
What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#firstname').blur(function() {
    var fn = $('#firstname').val();
    $('#add').val(fn);
  });
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
      include('conn.php');
      $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `user`");
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <?php echo $row['firstname']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $row['lastname']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $row['address']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#edit<?php echo $row['userid']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Edit</a>
          <?php include('editmodal.php'); ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php
        }
      ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<?php include('add_modal.php'); ?>
</div>



/*My Edit Modal*/


<div class="modal fade" id="edit<?php echo $row['userid']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <center>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit</h4>
        </center>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <?php
     $edit=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from user where userid='".$row['userid']."'");
     $erow=mysqli_fetch_array($edit);
    ?>
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <form method="POST" action="edit.php?id=<?php echo $erow['userid']; ?>">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                  <label style="position:relative; top:7px;">Firstname:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $erow['firstname']; ?>">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div style="height:10px;"></div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                  <label style="position:relative; top:7px;">Lastname:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                  <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $erow['lastname']; ?>">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div style="height:10px;"></div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                  <label style="position:relative; top:7px;">Address:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                  <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $erow['address']; ?>">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                  <label style="position:relative; top:7px;">Added:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                  <input type="text" name="address" id="add" class="form-control" value="">
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Save</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're only selecting one row - the first name row. You probably want to use a class instead of an id.

Comment: I didn't get what you want to do exactly. Further explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Further Explanation:  I have a table loaded with data from the database and an edit button againaist each of the table rows. When the edit button is clicked (for any row), a modal is launched and loaded with database data of that row (i.e firstname, lastname and address). The modal has one blank textfield. I want when a user blurs from the firstname textfield(in the modal), the content of the firstname textfield are loaded to the blank textfield via jQuer (or JS). Hope i'm clear this time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by giving the  a class and using  .closest() method to read the row that has been clicked a hence pick the relevant data for that row.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.add').val("");
$('.firstname').blur(function(){
  var $rows = $(this).closest(".rows");
  var fn = $rows.find('.firstname').val();
        $rows.find('.add').val(fn);
});

});
 </script>
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
   <thead>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Action</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <?php
    include('conn.php');
    
    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `user`");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
     ?>
     <tr class="rows">
      <td><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
      <td>
       <a href="#edit<?php echo $row['userid']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Edit</a>
       <?php include('editmodal.php'); ?>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <?php
    }
   
   ?>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```